# android coverflow with thumbnails

Tags: android, thumbnails, coverflow

Hi I want to create thumbnails for my coverFlow so how can I give Listener to Thumbnail button click to scroll the coverFlow ?

I want a result like this image

http://cfile23.uf.tistory.com/image/166A04124CF5E5904B9D62

Thanks for help .

Answer (score 0):

Here you find a library for that:

[CoverFlow](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/)

Happy Coding

Comment: ok I am using it but I dont know how to listen to button click

Comment: bind the `setOnItemClickListener` to a `button`, this is enought